# random number generator c++

Tags: c++, random

Okay im pretty new to c++ and im trying to get a random number generator to work. General idea is that for loop calls random generator every time and puts the random number into array. It basically works, only problem is that the number is not random. Every single time it prints out -842150451 which is kind of a problem.

```
int main()
{
    int *array;
    int size;
    cout << "Enter size of array: ";
    cin >> size;
    array = new int[size];
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        srand ( time(NULL) );
        int randomNumber;
        randomNumber = rand() % 10000 + 1;
        randomNumber >> array[x];
```

It is all part of a bigger sorting algorithm so i wont bother copying the whole thing since this is the problem part.

Comment: Please read the manual of all the functions you're using.

Comment: Try initializing srand outside of your loop.  Otherwise you are just creating a RNG with the same seed, since time is unlikely to change in the timespan of a short loop.

Comment: There is no printout of the numbers in the code you have shown. There is likely to be a problem with that too, and not just with srand, since this code does give different results between runs, even though the generated numbers in each run are the same, and they are in the expected range. Please show a minimal _working_ example that _exhibits the problem_.

Comment: @fpw: No, an empty parameter list for `main` is fine.

Comment: Wait -- what is **randomNumber >> array[x];** supposed to do?

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: Added that to my answer because it had high votes already

Comment: Insert daily <TAKE SRAND() OUTSIDE THE LOOP!> response here.

Answer (score 8):

Call `srand` before the loop. It initializes the generator based on the current time - if your loop is fast enough, you will initialize it with the same seed in every iteration, hence no real randomness. One initialization is enough.

Another problem that was pointed out by @ThomasPadron-McCarthy in one of the comments to your question: You are trying to get the value into the array using

```
randomNumber >> array[x];
```

If you didn't overload that operator, it is a shift operating that will alter the random number, but not store it into the array. Use this to store it:

```
array[x] = randomNumber;
```

Comment: I suppose with "every single time" he meant "in every place of my array when I print it".

Answer (score 2):

If you can, you should use C++11's `<random>`. It's not difficult at all, and is leaps and bounds ahead of `srand()` and the like.

```
#include <random>

...

std::mt19937 rng_engine(seed);
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(min, max);
array[x] = dist(rng_engine);
```

It is *somewhat* verbose, but you can simplify the last call with `std::bind`:

```
auto newrand = std::bind(dist, rng_engine);
array[x] = newrand();
```

A note about random number engines: if you're generating some more random numbers somewhere else in your code, try to use a single engine object (you can create several distributions, even for different types). `std::mt19937` stores 624 32-bit integers to keep state; that's approximately 2.5 KiB of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Since your using C++ why don't you do it the C++ way?

Here is some sample code (you can taylor this to your app):

```
#include <random>

int main()
{
    // A Mersenne Twister pseudo-random generator:
    typedef std::mt19937 CppRNG;

    // Seed the generator:
    uint32_t seed_val = 0;
    CppRNG RandomGenerator;
    RandomGenerator.seed(seed_val);

    int min = 1; // use your val
    int max = 50; // use your val

    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint32_t> uniformMinMax(min, max);

    int r1 = uniformMinMax(RandomGenerator);
    int r2 = uniformMinMax(RandomGenerator);

 //... and so on

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems in your code. One is the **srand** called in each iteration, as explained by fpw. But what do you think this line does?

```
randomNumber >> array[x];
```

If you expect it to copy randomNumber to a place in the array, that is not what it does. Instead it shifts some bits, and throws away the result. So when you later print the contents of the array, they will be unintialized garbage.